# how to find specific files in a directory with a pythonic code?

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

i am looking for specific files in a directory with many subdirectories

is there a pythonic way to rewrite this? I want to avoid the first for loop if possible:

```
mytypes = [".txt", ".doc", ".docx"]

for ext in mytypes:
    for filename in glob.iglob(directory+"/**/*/"+ext, recursive=True):
        print(filename)
```

thank you if you can point me to right direction. This works fine but I want to optimize the code because the list of mytypes might get bigger and the directory is heavy.
This is what I tried but I believe there is a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter only some files, you will still need to have a `mytypes` variable.

With that said you can use the pythonic way of avoiding `for` loops: list comprehensions.

```
mytypes = [".txt", ".doc", ".docx"]

files = [f for ext in mytypes for f in glob.glob(directory+"/**/*/"+ext)]

print(files)
```

Comment: so i guess there is no way to avoid one for loop. yes thank you for your answer